# Multiple KeyGestures for a single RoutedUICommand

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

Is it possible to have 2 or more `KeyGestures` for a single `RoutedUICommand`?

*For example:* User wants to be able to press <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Alt+P</kbd> to play a video.

Currently, if I set both `KeyGestures` to a `RoutedUICommand`, it will expect both to be pressed to execute.

```
private static RoutedUICommand _play  = new RoutedUICommand("Play", "Play", typeof(Commands), 
   new InputGestureCollection 
       { 
            new KeyGesture(Key.P, ModifierKeys.Alt, "Alt + P"),
            new KeyGesture(Key.Space, ModifierKeys.None, "Space")
       });
```

So, can I set multiple `KeyGestures` to a single `RoutedUICommand`? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can add multiple keyBindings for same Command like below,

```
<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Alt" Key="P" Command="{Binding PlayCommand}" />
    <KeyBinding Key="Space" Command="{Binding PlayCommand}" />        
</UserControl.InputBindings>
```

Comment: Great. Can I register the `KeyBindings` directly to the `RoutedUICommand`?